# CSS3 animations not in sync on IE/Edge

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, css-animations

I have a simple animation running on an element which loops moving a "star" element from place to place using absolute positioning. It fades in and out briefly using opacity before moving to the next location, then repeating. This works fine in Chrome and Firefox, but of course IE/Edge is having issues. It can best be seen here: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/t0rlan/pen/qJXKoQ)

**Issue:** In IE/Edge the animation runs correctly through the first iteration, but as soon as the animation starts looping, the opacity and absolute position changes get out of sync to the point where the "star" is fading in/out WHILE it's moving which shouldn't be the case. Chrome shows the ideal animation steps: Fade In, Fade out, Move, Stop, Repeat.

Here's the code:

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Mr+Dafoe);
@-webkit-keyframes star-effect {
    0% {
        left: -7%;
        top: 44%;
        opacity: 0;
    }
    5% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    10% {
        left: -7%;
        top: 44%;
        opacity: 0;
    }
    35% {
        left: 44%;
        top: 0%;
        opacity: 0;
    }
    40% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    45% {
        left: 44%;
        top: 0%;
        opacity: 0;
    }
    70% {
        left: 90%;
        top: 6%;
        opacity: 0;
    }
    75% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    80% {
        left: 90%;
        top: 6%;
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        left: -7%;
        top: 44%;
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
body{
    background: #000;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 50px;
    font-size: 16px;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
h1{
    position: relative;
    height: 1.35em;
    line-height: 1;
    font-size: 10rem;
    margin: 0;
    transition: font-size .2s linear;
}
h1 > span:nth-child(1){
    position: absolute;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    top: 0px;
    font-family: 'Mr Dafoe', cursive;
    font-size: .87em;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    color: #fd5afa;
    text-shadow: -2px -2px 0 #FFBAF2;
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(3px 3px 1px #441F62);
    -webkit-transform: skew(-5deg,-5deg);
    font-weight: normal;
    z-index: 2;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
h1 span.star{
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    left: -7%;
    top: 44%;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    z-index: 4;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-animation-name: star-effect;
            animation-name: star-effect;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 6s;
            animation-duration: 6s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
            animation-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
            animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
h1 span.star:before{
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(#fff 20%, transparent 80%);
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    display: block;
    top: 50%;
}
h1 span.star:after{
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(#fff 0%, transparent 90%);
    width: 2px;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>
    <span>Word<span class="star"></span></span>
  </h1>
</body>
```

Comment: Try animating the `transform` property instead of `top` and `left`. I can't guarantee it's the problem with IE/Edge, but it's more performant.

Comment: I try to make a test and able to produce the issue in Edge but am not sure what exactly cause this issue. As a work around you can try to refer example below. it is working correctly in Edge. https://jsfiddle.net/bc_rikko/qwbfkv6y/